# How to find the minimum value in a Dict{key:List}?

Tags: python

I am trying to find the minimum flight price in a dictionary that looks like:

```
{datetime.date(2018, 12, 16): ['KL', 'AMS', '59.84'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 24): ['KL', 'AMS', '59.84'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 25): ['KL', 'AMS', '59.84'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 27): ['KL', 'AMS', '59.84'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 18): ['KL', 'AMS', '59.84'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 19): ['KL', 'AMS', '59.84'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 20): ['KL', 'AMS', '59.84'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 23): ['KL', 'AMS', '59.84'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 17): ['AF', 'AMS', '70.24'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 21): ['SK', 'AMS', '97.93'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 26): ['SK', 'AMS', '97.93'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 28): ['SK', 'AMS', '97.93'],
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 2): ['SK', 'AMS', '97.93'],
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 3): ['SK', 'AMS', '97.93'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 29): ['AF', 'AMS', '111.64'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 31): ['EW', 'AMS', '127.51'],
  datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): ['EW', 'AMS', '127.51'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 30): ['EW', 'AMS', '147.51'],
  datetime.date(2018, 12, 22): ['KL', 'AMS', '148.84']}
```

The first key is a datetime, and value = list of info.   I'm trying to simply get the max and min price over that time series.  I've tried the following:

```
_tempPairAndPrices = {}
for item in permutations(destinations[1:],2):    
    #try:
    key_max = max(_fltDictTemp_CachedData[item].keys(),key=(lambda k: _fltDictTemp_CachedData[item][k]))
    key_min = min(_fltDictTemp_CachedData[item].keys(),key=(lambda k: _fltDictTemp_CachedData[item][k]))
    maxPx = _fltDictTemp_CachedData[item][key_max]
    minPx = _fltDictTemp_CachedData[item][key_min]

    _tempPairAndPrices[item] = {'maxPx':maxPx,'minPx':minPx}
```

I don't think it's properly accessing the list of information though, as it's not properly assigning max and min values...    (often my min >> max)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, use [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) with a `key`

```
[min(v.values(), key=lambda x: float(x[-1])) for k,v in d.items()]
```

Outputs

```
[['KL', 'AMS', '59.84']]
```

---

For your edited data, just do

```
min(d.values(), key=lambda x: float(x[-1]))
```

Comment: thanks, it looks like it's close but I'm getting a 'list' object has no attribute 'values' error

Comment: @keynesiancross `d` is your outter dictionary. Do `d.items()` should give you a tuple as `key` and another `dict` as values. Check if that is what happening :)

Comment: ah, I actually skipped that step because I'm, earlier, setting d = originalDict[tupleKey].  All I'm left with is a key(datetime) and the output list

Comment: @keynesiancross so it gets even simpler

Answer (score 1):

If you are just interested in getting the minimum flight price, this is one possible solution:

```
prices = [float(i) for i in np.array(dict.values()[0].values())[:,-1]]
min_price = min(prices)
```

where `dict` is your dictionary. The reason I used `np.array()` in the list comprehension was in order to use the indexing `[:,-1]` since the prices are the last element of the list. But I see there are several prices which are equal and the minimum. I don't know how you plan to tackle them. You can of course combine the above two lines into one and write:

```
min_price = min([float(i) for i in np.array(dict.values()[0].values())[:,-1]])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting a "dict_values" object does not support indexing error where you use [0]

Comment: Strange. I just copied your first code snippet as dict = {.....} and it worked for me. Well I used Python 2.7.12 so may be that is an issue?